# Clean SDF database file

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I have a filled SDF database file, I need to clean every record of tables. But if I do it by hand, Primary keys will not start with 1 after add record in table. And records will create with id (for example 4091+). So, how can I delete all data and set all primary keys to 1.

My database is too large and have many associations, because of this I cannot just delete all tables and create new. It takes a lot of time.

Sorry for my English.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need IDs to start at 1 again if you're deleting all the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `truncate` the table...

```
TRUNCATE TABLE tbl_name
```

`Truncate` deletes all the record along with resetting the id equal to 0.

If TRUNCATE not available in your database, you can simply delete the record

`DELETE from tbl_name`

and reset the Identity column in following way:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name ALTER COLUMN id IDENTITY (1,1)
```

Comment: ALTER TABLE tbl_name ALTER COLUMN id IDENTITY (1,1) - this is what i need

Comment: and "DELETE from tbl_name" is useful

Comment: If you are using other database like sql server, you have choice for TRUNCATE....

Answer (score 0):

just use `DELETE` command.

```
DELETE FROM tableName
```

and it will entirely delete all rows on the table.